# How to place child element without being affected of transformation of parent element? UPDATED!!! [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, transform, cartesian-coordinates

I have a parent div that displays a graph that can be rotated. 
I want to place dots at mouse clicks. This is my place function:

```
module.exports.place = function (event, id) {
  let div = document.createElement("div");
  div.className = "container-fluid";
  div.id = id;
  let avakio_wrapper = document.getElementById("avakio");
  avakio_wrapper.appendChild(div);
  let parentPosition = getPosition(event.currentTarget);

  xPosition = event.clientX - parentPosition.x - div.clientWidth / 2;
  yPosition = event.clientY - parentPosition.y - div.clientHeight / 2;
  div.style.left = xPosition + "px";
  div.style.top = yPosition + "px";
}
```

When the graph isn't rotated it works as expected, though when i rotate the graph it places the dot first under mouse click and then it applies the rotation transform and moves it. I have screenshots showing what i describe. The red dot is showing the click position. I appreciate any help.

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE!!!!**

Here is an implementation of my code:

```
// Calculate clicking pos based of top-left corner of div
  xPosition = event.clientX - parentPosition.x - dot.clientWidth / 2;
  yPosition = event.clientY - parentPosition.y - dot.clientHeight / 2;

  let centerx = parentDiv.clientWidth / 2;
  let centery = parentDiv.clientHeight / 2;

  // Find Rotation angle
  let rot = parentDiv.style.getPropertyValue("transform");
  if (rot != "") {
    rot = rot.split("(")[1].split("deg")[0];
  } else {
    rot = 0;
  }

  // Perform Invert Rotation
  xPosition = centerx - xPosition;
  yPosition = centery - yPosition;

  let xRot =
    xPosition * Math.cos(rot * (Math.PI / 180)) +
    yPosition * Math.sin(rot * (Math.PI / 180));
  let yRot =
    -xPosition * Math.sin(rot * (Math.PI / 180)) +
    yPosition * Math.cos(rot * (Math.PI / 180));

  // Calculate again based top-left corner
  dot.style.left = centerx - xRot + "px";
  dot.style.top = centery - yRot + "px";
```

However i run on some issues. When the parent div is rotated the dots are placed some pixels off based on the rotation angle. I have some screenshots of different rotation angles. I' ve done the maths on paper for many days but still can't figure out what causing it.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You can either dont put the mouse dots in rotated element : `<div id="parent"><div id="rotated"></div><div name="dot"></div></div>`. Or store the actual rotation value in a var, and using it to calulate the actual postiton of dots.

Comment: Please consider creating a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your current issue with [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) or other available tools like [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net) or [codepen.io](https://codepen.io) for us.

Comment: @JulienMaret i want them to be part of the graph and rotate with it later that's why i use them as childNodes. I thought that i can use the rotation value to calculate the top and left values differently but i can't figure out the maths.

Comment: https://calculator.academy/rotation-calculator-new-coordinates-by-rotation/. First get the center of you graph and calculate you point coordianate. Then apply formulas : 
X=xcos(θ)+ysin(θ)

Y=−xsin(θ)+ycos(θ)

Calculate the the real posistion  (first step backward).

Example : graph is 100x100, your point is (15,30) from the top left corner.

center : (50,50) ; point : (50-15, 50-30) = (35,20)

point rotated  of 30deg, formula give  rounded (40,0)

to normal : (50-40, 50-0) = (10,50)

So your real point poistion is (10,50) instead of (15,30), when the parent is rotated of 30deg

Comment: Thank you @JulienMaret your solution solved my problem just right!

Comment: The answer or just formulas?

Answer (score 1):

Here an application of the math.
They still move a bit (I think that is because of calculus imprecision). I'm kinda stuck here, maybe some will be able to fix it.

```js
function rotate() {
  let parent = document.getElementById("parent")
  let rot = document.getElementById("value").value
  let transform = parent.style.transform
  transform = "rotate("+ (Number(transform.substr(7,transform.length-11)) + Number(rot)) +"deg)"
  parent.style.transform = transform
  let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot")
 for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++)
  dotpos(parent, dots[i],rot)
}

function dotpos(parent,dot,rot) {
 rot = rot * (Math.PI/180) //convert to radian
 let xCenter = parent.offsetWidth /2
 let yCenter = parent.offsetHeight /2
 let x = xCenter - Number(dot.style.left.substring(0, dot.style.left.length - 2))
 let y = yCenter - Number(dot.style.top.substring(0, dot.style.top.length - 2))
 let xRot = x*Math.cos(rot)+y*Math.sin(rot)
 let yRot = -x*Math.sin(rot)+y*Math.cos(rot)
 dot.style.left = xCenter -xRot + "px"
 dot.style.top = yCenter -yRot + "px"
}
```

```css
#parent {
  height: 100px;
  width : 100px;
  background-color: grey;
}
.dot {
  height: 5px;
  width : 5px;
  border-radius: 5px; 
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" style = "transform:rotate(0deg)">
  <div class ="dot" style="position:relative;left:15px;top:30px;"></div>
  <div class ="dot" style="position:relative;left:60px;top:50px;"></div>
</div>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="value"><br>
</form>

<button onclick="rotate()">rotate</button>
```